# Inserting a line in text file through perl is failing

Tags: perl

I am trying to insert a new row on 2nd line of text file using perl . But it keeps failing.

I am using below command to achieve the same.

```
  perl -ni -e "print; print \"permissibleCars = [ ${part[*]} ]\n\" if $. == 2" query/containerId_count.js
```

But I keep getting error :--

```
 root@vm-test-001:~/mongosearch# distinct_array=`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' output/ontainerId_distinct.txt`
 root@vm-test-001:~/mongosearch# declare -a arr=($distinct_array)
 root@vm-test-001:~/mongosearch# batchsize=1
 root@vm-test-001:~/mongosearch# IFS=,
 root@vm-test-001:~/mongosearch# part=( "${arr[@]:i:batchsize}" )
 root@vm-test-001:~/mongosearch# echo $part
 "C:00000092666270:53882159774"
 root@vm-test-001:~/mongosearch# perl -ni -e "print; print \"permissibleCars = [ ${part[*]} ]\n\" if $. == 2" query/containerId_count.js
 Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ""permissibleCars = [ "C"
    (Missing operator before C?)
String found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "53882159774" ]\n""
    (Missing operator before " ]\n"?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near ""permissibleCars = [ "C"
Illegal octal digit '9' at -e line 1, at end of line
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Can you help me with same ?

Regards

Comment: Tried that but it didnt  work :-- Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

Comment: >> `perl -ni -e 'print; print "permissibleCars = [ \${part[*]} ]\n" if $. == 2'`

Comment: This wont give error but it will not copy the data stored in variable rather it copied permissibleCars = [ ${part[*]} ] as text.

Comment: So, add to the question what `${part[*]}` should return in your case.

Comment: that is already there :-- root@vm-test-001:~/mongosearch# echo $part
 "C:00000092666270:53882159774"

Comment: `${part[*]}` => `$ENV{part}`

Comment: This also didnt help

Comment: Look at $part. It's a string wrapped in quotes. And perl sees this `print "permissibleCars = [ "C:00000092666270:53882159774" ]\n"`.

Comment: @user2854333 You are in linux so use single quote to run the one liner.  `perl -ni -e 'print; print  "..." '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
export PARTS=${part[*]}
perl -lni -e 'print; print "permissibleCars = [".join(",",split/ /,$ENV{PARTS})."]" if $. == 2' query/containerId_count.js
```

And
In linux platform we should use single quote for one liner. From [Perl black book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6kCWinNuop4C&pg=PA1&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false) see page number 19 and 20.

Comment: No, this seems to be having strange issue . It is randomly adding adding ] and triming the objects inside array .

Comment: @user2854333 Then what is the output you get with this command here? Looks like the issue is with how you construct `${part[*]}`.

Comment: It is a array which hold holds value as subset from array. It can be like "C:1000817:57160911940","C:1000817:57176485410","C:1000817:57205942228","C:1000817:57211484466","C:1000817:57215240125","C:1000817:57218809582","C:1000817:57221636702","C:1000817:57235388574","C:1000817:
57237335061","C:1000817:57239290315","C:1000817:57250543857","C:1000817:57250575736","C:1000817:57303722225","C:1000860:379598081","C:1000882:379598272","C:1000960:379598451"

Comment: Also, I was able to do using sed but  it is POSIX standard sed implementation, the byte length limit is 8192 bytes.

Comment: Ok, got it. And then in your perl script, do you need `part` as an array, or as a flat string?

Comment: when it inserts into a js file i want the second line as permissibleCars = [ "C:1156646:3445705296","C:1156646:54617499","C:1156666:54619560","C:1157183:54673215","C:1157748:1725390682"]

Comment: Note I just updated the answer. This should fix several issues.

Comment: Thank you. I think my initial issue is with Mongo itself where it is not taking complete list.

Comment: Did this perl command work for you? You can `echo $PARTS` to see if the list is complete.

Comment: Downvoting went a bit rude here. It was an obvious syntax problem right from the beginning. Nice day.